# Return Excel file from django view to html for downloading at client

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a django app in which excel file is generated at server side and I want that to be downloaded at client.
I am sending​ request through Ajax call in JavaScript that goes to server generates excel which needs to be downloaded.
The view should generate http response that sends excel file to html that could be downloaded to a file at client

Answer (score 3):

It's not as complicated as you may think. In fact, as I understand, you have a Django model and you need to export some instances' data in an .xlsx file for example.

I'd suggest the following simple solution:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

def method(request, **kwargs):
    queryset = ModelName.objects.filter()   # adjust accordingly

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=this-is-your-filename.xlsx'
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
    ws.title = "Your Title"

    row_num = 0

    columns = [
        ("ID", 5),
        (u'Name', 20),
    ]

    for col_num in range(len(columns)):
        c = ws.cell(row=row_num + 1, column=col_num + 1)
        c.value = columns[col_num][0]
        ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(col_num + 1)].width = columns[col_num][1]

    for obj in queryset:
        row_num += 1
        row = [
            obj.pk,
            obj.name,
        ]
        for col_num in range(len(row)):
            c = ws.cell(row=row_num + 1, column=col_num + 1)
            c.value = row[col_num]

    wb.save(response)
    return response
```

Please keep in mind that you need to install with `pip install openpyxl` the `openpyxl` lib first.

Comment: Actually I am using xlsxwriter to generate excel file and save it on the server. Can I send this saved .xlsx file as a http response ?

Comment: I cannot think of a reason you cannot do it. You have to set the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header in your response, as well as the correct `content_type`.

Comment: Ok thanks ....I'll try this once ..and do I need to add anything in html too or the return response would automatically Download the file

Comment: It should automatically prompt the user to download the file

Comment: I am getting the response at the website but download prompt is'nt appearing

Comment: Please mind checking as correct my answer if you think it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I had to complete this exact task and ended up using the following method. Instead of using an AJAX call, I just do

```
window.location.pathname = "/relative/path/to/url/"
```

within Javascript click handler for the button.

Within Django, I am using the following code (I am using XlsxWriter but you could use whatever you wish for creating XLSX file):

```
    excel_file = BytesIO()
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(excel_file)

    # Code to populate the workbook

    # Here comes the magic
    workbook.close()
    excel_file.seek(0)
    response = HttpResponse(excel_file.read(),
                            content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=somename.xlsx'
    return response
```

When called this way, the created Excel file is downloaded and the user remains on the calling page, which is the exact behavior I wanted.